# Graph / Tree Visualization Software

Tags: programming, graph-theory

I am planning to begin teaching Computer Science topics in video/slide form. I would like to be able to easily create visualizations of trees and graphs (and other data structures would be great as well). I have seen some other educators have great visualizations that allow them to beautifully visualize these concepts and even step through and highlight nodes or edges to make the content more engaging. However, I have tried googling and I can't seem to find software that does this well. I am open to either free or paid options, does anyone know any good software or tooling for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> easily create visualizations of trees and graphs.

- [Visio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio)
  The easiest way is to use a tool like Visio. It is [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG).

  Also see [13 Free Alternatives to Microsoft Visio](https://www.maketecheasier.com/5-best-free-alternatives-to-microsoft-visio/)

---

- [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/)
  Very popular. Works with different grammars for defining the graphs with [DOT](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) being the most commonly used. Somewhat easy after you get past your fist few.
- [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/)
  PlantUML is used to draw UML diagrams, using a simple and human readable text description. GraphViz must be installed to use. Also has an [online server](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000).
- [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/)
  Graph theory (network) library for visualisation and analysis. Works with JavaScript, HTML and JSON to create interactive HTML pages. Not easy to learn and use but once mastered can make dynamic graphs and even animate them, e.g. walking a tree.
- [D3](https://d3js.org/)
  D3.js is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data.
- [GoJS](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html?v220)
  A Web Framework for Rapidly Building Interactive Diagrams.
- [LabVIEW](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/labview/select-edition/labview-community-edition.html) Community Edition
  LabVIEW offers a graphical programming approach to help you visualize every aspect of your application, including hardware configuration, measurement data, and debugging.
- [Restructured Text](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html)
  Markup Syntax and Parser Component of Docutils. The web sites can even include interactive content. [Example](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/OpenDSA/Books/PL/html/index.html)
- [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)
  LaTeX is a software system for document preparation.
  Diagrams in research papers are typically made using LaTeX. LaTeX is not easy. LaTeX is a Turning complete programming language with packages, hierarchies, add-ins, etc. For writing technical math notation this is a popular option.
- [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)
  Beautiful and accessible math in all browsers
- [MarkDown](https://www.markdownguide.org/)
  Markdown makes writing on the web fast and easy.
- Web pages
  [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) - The language for building web pages.
  [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) - The language we use to style an HTML document.
  [Sass](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/) - Reduces repetition of CSS and therefore saves time.
  [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) - The programming language of the Web.
- [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html)
  Doxygen is the de facto standard tool for generating documentation from annotated C++ sources, but it also supports other popular programming languages such as C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL and to some extent D.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated!

Comment: Definitely Dot. Ultra simple input format, which I often generate from another program, rather than by hand.

Comment: Of interest: [Handbook of Graph Drawing and Visualization](https://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/) - Algorithms for laying out an drawing edge-vertex graphs.

Comment: If you like this answer you should bookmark it. That way when I update this you will know. :)